# Website Architecture - Control/Object Loading Based on Config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, design-patterns, configuration

I am building a site which will need to change slightly in certain markets. For example, in a UK market, the signup form needs to perform address validation (already have this working), and on a Belgium site, we need to verify a person with a web service (already have this working). Otherwise, signup functionality is basically the same. We have these two sites working independently, but we'd like to merge them into a single codebase which can support either option based on config.

My initial thought was to use a configuration value to say "This is a UK site" or "This is a Belgium site" and display the pages based on this setting.

Ideas:

- Dependency injection to load controls dynamically based on config
- Factory pattern to use Reflection/Activator and load dynamically based on config
- Config transforms to load different user controls by setting a tagname/tagprefix
- Other?

Does anyone have any first thoughts on recommendations on where I can find inspiration for this type of design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to keep it as simple and minimal as possible.

Simply create something like `IPersonValidator` which has a `.Validate(PersonDetails)` method and returns an array of errors.

Edit:

On the config side, you could create a custom config section of the following structure:

```
<DomainSpecificSettings>
 <Key name="validator">
  <Value domain="www.yoursite.co.uk" value="firstValidator" />
  <Value domain="www.yoursite.de" value="secondsValidator" />
 </Key>
</DomainSpecificSettings>
```

One more thing - you don't need to use Activator. You could have a singleton Validators store which holds a single instance for each validator type and knows how to find the correct Validator according to the database config setting of the currently viewd market:

```
ValidatorsStore.GetValidator(string configValue).Validate(PersonDetails).
```

The design in this case may easily become a overkill for such a simple task. My approach is to first make it work good enough, and only then check if you need to make it more robust. Most chances are that you won't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This makes sense to me. Just a few questions:

- Each "Market" would necessarily require a new deployment. My thought with putting it in Config is that once it's set for a deployment, it would never change. That site remains as that specific implementation (UK or Belgium, or other)
- For the configValue, do you see a benefit in having the URL as the value? For example "sitename.co.uk" vs "sitename.be"? This is subjective but just looking for thoughts. :)

Comment: Are you planning to use exactly the same code but deploy it to two different locations? if so then i misunderstood your question :) anyway, if this is the case then storing it in the config makes a bit more sense. you could use the Strategy Design Pattern here. each "strategy" will be a class or a collection of classes implementing the same interface - exactly as in my provided example. It sounds like you are going to have more "splits" in the flow so you could hold different strategies for all of them in some sort of a StrategyProvider class. Was that too vague or did you get my point?

Comment: This is definitely helpful. And yes, same codebase with exact deployment to all production environments, but a configuration flag to denote which version of the site to use (also open to suggestions on this, but it seems to be the preferred approach by everyone else here.) I'm somewhat familiar with the Strategy pattern but not specific to this example. I'll have to review a bit more. Really just trying to get ideas where to start.

Comment: by strategy i mean to load a different strategy depending on the domain. Did you think about accessing same code exatcly (only a single deployment) but with different domain names? another idea i had was to implement the config key as a custom config section section. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you again. Due to regulatory restrictions, our deployments necessarily have to be hosted within the country they are for. So the UK and BE sites are not linked in any way. The domain name won't necessarily change but not certain if basing it on the URL is the best idea (how does that work in testing scenarios on IP, localhost, or internal hostnames?) There wouldn't be a problem with setting one or more config values for each environment if that is easier to implement (we should have auto deploy with Puppet soon, hopefully!)

Comment: Marking this as an answer as it's given me a lot to think about, but may post a few more comments here for suggestions if you're willing to let me bounce them off you!

Answer (score 1):

First, as you mention “loading user controls”, think it will be better to separate the presentational part of the implementation from the logic/validation itself. You could create(or refine) a generic user control that works for all the countries but calls logic that does the address validation in case of the UK or nothing in case of BE. Single responsibility principle or separation of concerns in the MVC world.

Also use same principles separate the different components of the page in different user controls with their logic. Every component with have their own validation before calling the final signup/register. This way you can notify the player of a validation error in the input data without having to require the full player information to do the signup. Once the full information for the player is provided and validated you can call the signup that just saves the player in the database.

About the StrategyProvider class to decide which logic to call, agree with Uri, we are going to have many places where the logic varies a between countries. But it is not something we could setup with IoC container? Don’t know much about IoC containers but if logic is “static” (when you are in website it does not change depending on request) could be possible to setup it at application start time.

Another possibility is to use the SOA pattern and call different services depending on the website you are in. (same servuces end points could be setup in config). Services for the different countries can have different logic but return a class that follows a common interface (use Adapter pattern).

Comment: Very good information. Agreed that the location-specific logic can be sorted quite a bit in the actual user control. What I'm not too certain about (yet) is how to determine which user control to load. Technically since this will be in Umbraco the determination *could* be made there, but ideally from a config to remove the dependence on the CMS. I think the generic user control idea you mentioned solves this problem. So much to think about! :)

Comment: The user control should be pasted on Masterpage. Most likely that not the masterpage will be different for the different countries.
In this case you can paste a different user control or have a parameter to determine the view mode. 
If the masterpage is the same but user control (ex. address input) is different should be some logic maybe in the masterpage that decides (depending on Url, config…) which control to load dynamically (Strategy pattern LoadControl("~/xxxxControl.ascx")) or feeds a parameter view mode.

Comment: Maybe the first complication is to try to use dependency injection pattern in ASP.NET forms but is possible as explaned [here](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/10/enabling-dependency-injection-in-web.html) or [here](http://ayende.com/blog/2756/rhino-igloo-mvc-framework-for-web-forms).  It should be easier if using Umbraco 6 with MVC as this is one of the reason for MVC to exist. [An MVC example](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx)